# Message getBody null when listening on mailer.sending event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

I'm trying to capture the body of an email sent through Laravel's Mail class.  Listening on the event `mailer.sending` allows me to get a `Swift_Message` object, however, when I call `getBody()` it returns null.

I can, however, use the __toString() magic method to print out the entire email (with headers).  Anyone know if there is a way to get the body of the email?

Using tinker ($message is retrieved from the Event firing):

```
>>> $message
=> <Swift_Message #000000004598a18f0000000059c6cf6b> {}
>>> $message->getBody(); 
=> null
>>> echo (string) $message;
Message-ID: <135138ac89676fd3487ff75b10989803@swift.generated>
Date: Fri, 07 Oct 2016 22:41:02 +0000
Subject: ...
From: ...
To: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="_=_swift_v4_1475880062_895bd5de56ade4842a3c198ee264ced0_=_"


--_=_swift_v4_1475880062_895bd5de56ade4842a3c198ee264ced0_=_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Email body here

--_=_swift_v4_1475880062_895bd5de56ade4842a3c198ee264ced0_=_--
```

Comment: I can not see in which way you are using the library but are you sure that in your contest you need to use  `$message->getBody(); ` instead of `$message->setBody();`

Comment: This is captured from Laravel's event firing.  I am using $message->getBody() but it returns null for some reason.

Comment: I understand that you trying to get the message. Did you have set the message while using the library?  In this way `$message->setBody($body_text) where `$body_text` can be your template if you are using one or this way which I prefer `$message->addPart($body_text , 'text/html');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging into the Laravel code, they use a Mime part instead of the body for plain text emails.  (Maybe this is due to Swiftmailer design, I don't know the library well enough).

A quick solution to this for me was:

```
        $htmlBody = $message->getBody();
        $textBody = '';
        $children = $message->getChildren();
        if (isset($children[0]) && $children[0] instanceof \Swift_MimePart) {
            $textBody = $children[0]->getBody();
        }
        $body = ($htmlBody) ? $htmlBody : $textBody;
```

However, additional checks may be needed to make sure the first child is the plain text email.  Hopefully this helps someone else who runs into the issue.